# AngularJS line break at points after a maximum length was reached

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` to fill a table. Some elements have a pretty long length, and I'm looking for a way to cut the content into multiple lines, if a specific length is reached.

During research I found Angulars `limitTo`, but it does not exactly look like I was looking for.

E.g. `hi i'm a long description and oh, a package (org.foo.awesome.stuff)` should convert into `hi i'm a long description and oh,'`
 `a package (org.foo.awesome.stuff)`

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a custom filter:

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter('lineBreaker', function() {
  return function(input, breakLength) {
    var newString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      newString = newString+input[i];
      if (i%breakLength == 0) {
        newString = newString+"\n";
      }
    }
    return newString;
  };
});
```

Called like:

```
{{ expression | lineBreaker: 10 }}
```

I'm sure there is a more performant way to do this, but it will get the job done.

Comment: You should probably make length a variable for the filter, in order to encourage reuse.

Comment: Looks nice so far, but wouldn't it cut a word in two? Guess i have to implement a own "point-consideration" :) Thanks man!

Comment: Yeah, there are definitely limitations here like that, so you'll need to iron it out to suit your needs. Honestly, a RegEx is probably the way to go

Answer (score 2):

```
app.filter("break", function(){
    return function(input, length){
        return input.match(new RegExp(".{1," + length + "}", 'g')).join("<br/>");
    }
});
```

Comment: A little more explanation of what sets this answer apart from the other answers (including the accepted one) would be great! I don't think this solves the performance problem identified in the accepted answer, which would be nice to see in any more recent responses.

Comment: It is just simpler. I added my answer because I think SO is a knowledge base. People can chose more relevant answer for their problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following to insert a line break every `limit` characters:

```
var a = "hi i'm a long description and oh, a package (org.foo.awesome.stuff)";
var limit = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   if (i % (limit + 1) === 0 && i > 0) {
      a = [a.slice(0, i), '\n', a.slice(i)].join('');
   }
}

console.log(a);

/** Output:
  hi i'm a lo
  ng descrip
  tion and o
  h, a packa
  ge (org.fo
  o.awesome.
  stuff)"
*/
```

Throw that into a custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution would be to use CSS to modify the word-wrap of the text in the elements of a table.
e.g.

```
th {
word-wrap:normal;
}
td {
word-wrap:normal;
}
```

In addition to this, you would probably have to edit the width of your table elements so that word-wrapping will occur (instead of creating a box as long as your text). This can be simply achieved by editing the css styling as shown in the following code. There are two options (depending on if you want your webpage to be scaleable or not)

Option 1:

```
th {
width:300px;
}
...
```

Option 2:

```
td {
width:10%
}
...
```

Also noteable about this solution, it DOES NOT break the given string at any word (unless otherwise told to do so). You can read more about word-wrap [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

Comment: this visually breaks the content. it doesn't directly answer the users question.

Comment: Shoot... ok but I was trying to go for an easier solution here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the best solution, since it does not break at words... And if scaling is an issue, just modify the css font-size to be something like: font-size: 1em.

Comment: Ok last edit. I am positive this works. If this does not answer the question, please explain in great detail and maybe change the original question as it may have misleading to me.

Comment: It is, for sure, a possible solution. And it does (!) answer my question in a way, not as pankajparkar pointed out. I'll see which approach will be used. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was going insane here haha! Best of luck!